# what's the difference? (Logistic Regression)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, logistic-regression

I am a student who studies AI

Why are the results above and below different?
Why is there a difference between one and two dimensions?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

torch.manual_seed(1)

x_data = [[10.0], [20.0], [30.0], [40.0], [50.0], [60.0], [70.0], [80.0], [90.0], [100.0]]
y_data = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_data)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(y_data)

W = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True)

optimizer = optim.SGD([W, b], lr=0.01)

num_epochs = 10000
for epoch in range(num_epochs + 1):

    eps = 1e-7

    hypothesis = 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-(x_train.matmul(W) + b)))
    loss = -(y_train * torch.log(torch.clamp(hypothesis, eps, 1-eps)) + (1 - y_train) * torch.log(torch.clamp(1 - hypothesis, eps, 1-eps))).mean()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print('Epoch {:4d}/{} Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch, num_epochs, loss.item()
        ))

hypothesis = torch.sigmoid(x_train.matmul(W) + b)
print(hypothesis)
```

This code works well when `y_data` is one-dimensional
It doesn't work in two dimensions.

two-dimensional meaning
`y_data = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]]`

The loss value stops at 0.693147.

Why is there a difference between one and two dimensions?